# HTML video stops playing after 1 minute and 50 seconds

Tags: html, html5-video

I have a video that is 2 minutes and 42 seconds in length. I have confirmed the video itself plays through and is not corrupted. The video plays fine up until the 1.50 mark and then abruptly stops.

```
<div class="video-container">
     <video controls preload>
        <source style="width: 100%; height:50%" src="splitscreen.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
     </video>
</div>

.video-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, confirm the video's length through JS:

```
 <video id="myVideo" controls preload="auto">
        <source style="width: 100%; height:50%" src="splitscreen.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
 </video>

<script>
    var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
    alert("Video duration is : " + vid.duration);
</script>
```

all I'm doing here is giving your video a ID, declaring a variable which holds `document.getElementById("myVideo")`, then checking it's length by using the `.duration` and alerting it. If you see your expected video's length:

> I have a video that is 2 minutes and 42 seconds in length.

Then I believe "controls preload" is your error here as the syntax is incorrect (should be `preload="auto"`), check [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_preload.asp) for great explanation about it.

Of-course if the video's length does show 1:50 in the alert, then the video is corrupted.
Best of luck!

Comment: The web page is giving me "Video duration is : NaN". Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using Media Fragments and see if this allows the entire video to be played.

```
<source style="width: 100%; height:50%" src="splitscreen.mp4.webm#t=0:00:00,00:02:42" type="video/mp4" />
```

Adding a media fragment to the media URL, you can specify the exact portion you want to play. To add a media fragment, you add #t=[start_time][,end_time].